# Google cloud print OAuth scope not found

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-print

I'm creating an app that prints out a pdf from the server after it has been generated.

When using google cloud print I keep getting:

```
User credentials required
Error 403
```

**Note:** making this print request in the [simulating page](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/simulate.html) works fine, but that's because I'm already logged into my google account.

After doing some research I found out I need to use OAuth to get an access token to send with the request to make a print job.

And every single page I can find tells me to redirect me to: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint, which gives me a 404 error, neither can I find it in the google playground, and using any older versions of authentication ends up in the request to sign in being flagged as an attack from a hacker.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What code are you using to call the API?

Comment: @Nick I posted this question over a year ago, I don't have any code I used anymore

Answer (score 8):

I was stuck on this for a while. The docs don't tell you which scope to use or how to use it. I haven't implemented a Google API using OAuth2 yet, so I didn't have an understanding of how the scoping works.

It turns out the scope is just the base API route for CloudPrint.

To make sure your `refresh_token` or `access_token` is scoped properly to use the CloudPrint API you need to use have the following string in your scope object:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint`